# how do I get the time member of a message struct for a message that arrived in a window procedure?

Tags: windows, winapi

For messages that arrive in my messagequeue after I use getmessage I can simply track the time by accessing the message structure returned by getmessage, but many messages are processed by the window procedure apart from the standard messageloop (for example CreateWindowEx prompts some messages to be processed in the window procedure).

For this reason I need to acquire the time member of the message struct in the windows procedure itself if I want to be able to get the timestamp for the messages that bypass the standard message queue loop. Is there any way to acquire the time member of a message sent to the windows procedure callback from within the windows procedure itself?

Comment: GetMessageTime()

Comment: I don't think you can directly get the time for sent messages. There is the GetMessageTime function, but it is documented to get the time of the last retrieval from GetMessage. You could always install a WH_CALLWNDPROC hook and save the time for each message prior to it being dispatched.

Comment: @Luke that only retrieves the time of a message obtained through GetMessage. I need the time of messages that bypass getmessage and go straight into the window procedure.

Comment: *"Is there any way to acquire the time member of a message sent to the windows procedure callback from within the windows procedure itself?"* - Since that was the result of a direct call, that timestamp would be *"now"* (or less than a microsecond before that).

Comment: @IInspectable not necessarily. If the message was sent by another thread, it has to wait until the receiving thread performs message retrieval in order for the message to be dispatched. So, which time is desired? The time the message was actually sent and had to wait, or the time the message was dispatched? They could be very different times.